# Assigning a field to a combo box

Tags: ms-access

I created a combo box that uses a `RowSource` of the days of the week that I typed in via the combo box wizard, and with a `RowSourceType` of `Value List`.

How do I get a field in my table to accept the selection made by the user?

Answer (score 0):

The table should be set in the `RecordSource` property of the form.

Then, set the `combobox`'s `ControlSource` property to the required field.

You do it this way regardless of `RowSourceType` being `ValueList`.